# Javascript returning string on what should be a shorthand boolean test

Tags: javascript, boolean

Can someone explain to me why this returns an empty string ("") instead of a boolean (false)?

```
var x = "";
alert(x && x.length > 0);
```

...While this works as expected, returning true:

```
var y = "abc";
alert(y && y.length > 0);
```

I am basically just trying to do a simple shorthand check to see if a value exists in a variable (ensuring it's not undefined, null, or empty string).

I know I can do each test individually (x == null, typeof x == 'undefined', x == '')  -  I'm just trying to understand why Javascript returns a string on what looks to be a boolean test.

Comment: note that you can force returning a `boolean` by using `!!(x)`

Comment: you should be able to shorten with something more like `alert(typeof x != undefined && x.length > 0)` because those both return bools, altho, if ever x is undefined, it may throw error (most likly) because 1st argument might error, would be better to split them up in mini func or inline

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When a conditional operator in JavaScript is satisfied, it returns the last value evaluated.

```
var x = "";
alert(x && x.length > 0);
```

An empty string is *falsey*, so when you use just `x` in a condition, it will be *false*. Because you are using `&&`, if the LHS is *false*, then there is no reason to bother checking the RHS. This is [short circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation). Therefore, the last evaluated part, the empty string, is returned to `alert()`.

```
var y = "abc";
alert(y && y.length > 0);
```

A non empty string is *truthy*. So the LHS is *true*, and because it's an `&&`, the RHS is evaluated (it needs to be to know if the entire condition is *true*). The return value of `y.length > 0` is `true`, so that is passed to your `alert()`.

Comment: in case this info helps to someone reading this, JS falsey values are= `0,"",false,null,undefined,NaN`

Answer (score 0):

It is returning and empty string because x is already defined, just empty.

This causes the first part of your expression `alert(x)` to show an empty string.

If you need to check for a null/empty string, try something like this.

```
String.isNullOrWhiteSpace = function (str) {
    if (typeof str === "string") {
        var isNullOrWhiteSpace = false;

        // Check for null string
        if (str == null || typeof str === "undefined") isNullOrWhiteSpace = true;

        // Check for string with whitespace
        if (str.replace(/\s/g, '').length < 1) isNullOrWhiteSpace = true;

        return isNullOrWhiteSpace;
    }

    if (typeof str === "undefined" || str == null) {
        return true;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The conditional operations using the `&&` (AND operator) will stop when:

- One of the conditions evaluated to `false`
- It successfully made it to the end by evaluating everything to `true`

The result of the conditional operations will be the last evaluated before stopping (not necessarily a `boolean`)

To force returning a *real* `boolean`, you can wrap everything around `!!(...)`, example:

```
alert(typeof !!(...) === "boolean"); //will always be true no matter what conditions are inside
```